# convert t-sql statement to teradata

Tags: teradata

I am trying to understand the equivalent of this statement

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Current') IS NOT NULL 
   DROP TABLE Current;
```

in Teradata.

Can someone help me out converting this statement to TD14. Thank you!

Comment: You would have to write a stored procedure to introduce IF THEN logic in Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in at least newer versions of TD:

```
select
count (*)
from
dbc.tablesv where tablename = '<your table>'
and databasename = '<your db>'
```

having count (*) > 0;

```
.if activitycount = 1  then .GOTO DropTable;
.if activitycount <> 1  then .quit;

.LABEL DropTable
select 'DROP TABLE!';
drop table <your db>.<your table>;
```

Sadly enough, this won't work with volatile tables.  If they are global temporary tables, you can use 
`select
count (*)
from
dbc.AllTempTablesVX where B_tablename =`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299329/create-table-but-drop-it-if-the-table-exists-already/9300195#9300195 ;)

Comment: No, I don't mean in a procedure.  That will run in SQL Assistant.

Comment: I know. The .IF command in you answer is for a BTEQ script. If you want to run in SQL Assistant you need a stored procedure to implement the logic condition.

Comment: No, that exact code (well, with real table and db names) will run as is in SQL Assistant.  No BTEQ or stored procs required.

Comment: Btw, a COUNT will always return a row :-)

Comment: Learned something about SQLA today. And as @dnoeth mentioned you should change `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT 1` which will return no rows if the table doesn't exist. Teradata Studio on the other hand doesn't like this approach. :)

Comment: Made a few changes based on @dnoeth's commments.